# How to return value from firestore database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am having a hard time returning a value from the firestore database.
I am trying to return the 'amount' from the database.
When setting the variable i am able to console.log the 'amount'. (see code)
But when i try to return the value at the end of the function, it does not return anything.('amount' is not defined  no-undef)
How can i return this value. Any help would be great. Please keep in mind that i am still quite new to this topic.

```
        import firebase from 'firebase/app';
        import 'firebase/firestore';
        import 'firebase/auth';

        export default function checkAmount() {

            let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

            if (user) {
                let userUID = user.uid
                let docRef = firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(userUID);

                docRef.get().then((doc) => {
                    if (doc.exists) {
                            let amount = doc.data().amount;
                            if (amount > 0){
                                console.log(amount) /// This does work
                            }
                        } else {
                            console.log("No such document!");
                        }
                    }).catch(function(error) {
                        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
                    });
            }

            return amount /// This **does not** return anything . How do i return the amount?
        }
```

Comment: could you share the structure in datastore please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is because the `get()` method is asynchronous: it returns immediately with a promise that resolves *some* time later with the results of the query. The `get()` method does not block the function (it returns immediately, as said above): this is why the last line (`return amount`) is executed before the asynchronous work is finished but with an undefined value.

You can read more [here](https://codingthesmartway.com/async-programming-with-javascript-callbacks-promises-and-async-await/) on asynchronous JavaScript methods and [here](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/why-are-firebase-apis-asynchronous-callbacks-promises-tasks-e037a6654a93?) on why Firebase APIs are asynchronous.

You therefore need to wait that the promise returned by the `get()` resolves and use the `then()` method, as Alex mentioned, to receive the query results and send the response.

The following will work:

```
    export default function checkAmount() {

        let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

        if (user) {
            let userUID = user.uid
            let docRef = firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(userUID);

            return docRef.get().then((doc) => {  //Note the return here
                if (doc.exists) {
                        let amount = doc.data().amount;
                        if (amount > 0){
                            console.log(amount) /// This does work
                            return true;  //Note the return here
                        }
                    } else {
                        console.log("No such document!");
                        //Handle this situation the way you want! E.g. return false or throw an error
                        return false;
                    }
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
                    //Handle this situation the way you want
                });
        } else {
           //Handle this situation the way you want
        }

    }
```

But you need to note that **your function is now also asynchronous**. Therefore you should call it as follows:

```
checkAmount().
then(result => {
  //Do whatever you want with the result value
  console.log(result);
})
```

Comment: Thanks! Now knowing that the function is asynchronous, this indeed did the trick.