# Retrieving data from one firestore document to query another

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I have 2 documents in a Firestore collection.

I want to query one document to get the number plate of a user, and with that number plate I want to retrieve the vehicle's data which is stored in the other document.

This is my code:

```
function get_full_name_by_nplate(nplate){
    var docRef = global_db.collection("customer_data").doc('web-app-vehicle-data');
    docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
        var data = doc.data();
        given_name = data["vehicles"][nplate]["policy_holder_given_name"];
        family_name = data["vehicles"][nplate]["policy_holder_family_name"];
    
        console.log("given name: " + given_name); //this prints correctly! ==> "Jaime"
    
        return given_name + " " + family_name;//this returns undefined
    });
}

//load user data ////driving scores from backend
function loadUserData(user){
    var nplate_list;

    var docRef = global_db.collection("customer_data").doc('web-app-user-data');
    docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
        var data = doc.data();
        user_data = data["users"][user.email];
        nplate_list = user_data["number_plates"];
    
    }).then(function(){

        for(nplate of nplate_list){
        
            get_full_name_by_nplate(nplate).then(full_name => {
                console.log(full_name);//this prints undefined
            });
        }
    });
}
```

I have read this answer [How to return value from firestore database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59537257/how-to-return-value-from-firestore-database) and I understand that Firestore returns promises so I always have to use `.then` after a Firestore data retrieval.

Although I am able to print the correct `given_name` to the console, the function `function get_full_name_by_nplate` returns `undefined`

What perhaps isn't working is that I am nesting one promise inside another, but I don't know if it is wrong to nest them, nor how to do it without nesting.

**UPDATE**

With the answer from @kvetis I have improved the code and now it works. However it still feels wrong, I had to pass `nplate_list` as a parameter from one `.then()` to the next one.. I wouldn't want to imagine if I had to pass it on 5 times, and additionally I am still nesting 2 `.then()` statements which also feels unnatural.

```
//load user data ////driving scores from backend
function loadUserData(user){



var docRef = global_db.collection("customer_data").doc('web-app-user-data');
    docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
        var data = doc.data();

        global_user_data = data["users"][user.email];
        //console.log(global_user_data["number_plates"]);

        var user_name  = global_user_data["name"] + " " + global_user_data["surname"];
        document.getElementById("welcome_div").innerHTML = user_name;

        var nplate_list = global_user_data["number_plates"];
        
        console.log("these are the nplates: " + nplate_list);
        
        return nplate_list;
    })
    
    .then(function (nplate_list) {
        var docRef = global_db
            .collection("customer_data")
            .doc("web-app-vehicle-data");
        
        docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
            global_vehicle_data = doc.data()["vehicles"];
            
            var cust_dropdown = document.getElementById("cust-search-dropdown");
            dropdown_content = "";
            
            for(nplate of nplate_list){
                //console.log(nplate);
                var full_name = get_full_name_by_nplate(global_vehicle_data, nplate);
                dropdown_content += "<div class=\"cust-dropdown-items\"><a href=\"#\" id=\"" + nplate + "\" class=\"number-plate-links\">" + nplate + " " + full_name + "</a></div>";
            }
            
            cust_dropdown.innerHTML = dropdown_content;
            addListeners();
            
            // If user has only 1 vehicle then pre-load it
            if(nplate_list.length == 1){
                select_customer_express(nplate_list[0]);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're probably reading `dropdown_content` before all the promises complete. You have to wait until all of `get_full_name_by_nplate` complete.

Unfortunately your code is written so, that you download the vehicle data over and over again.

What would be the best is to chain the two document loads one after other. Otherwise it will be slow and rather costly, since you're getting billed per document get.

```
function get_full_name_by_nplate(data, nplate) {

    given_name = data["vehicles"][nplate]["policy_holder_given_name"];
    family_name = data["vehicles"][nplate]["policy_holder_family_name"];

    return given_name + " " + family_name;
  
}

//load user data ////driving scores from backend
function loadUserData(user) {
  var nplate_list;

  var docRef = global_db.collection("customer_data").doc("web-app-user-data");
  docRef
    .get()
    .then(function (doc) {
      var data = doc.data();
      user_data = data["users"][user.email];
      nplate_list = user_data["number_plates"];
    })

    .then(function () {
      var docRef = global_db
        .collection("customer_data")
        .doc("web-app-vehicle-data");
      return docRef.get();
    })

    .then(function (doc)  { return doc.data()})

    .then(function (vehicle_data) {
      for (nplate of nplate_list) {
       var full_name=  get_full_name_by_nplate(vehicle_data,nplate);
          dropdown_content +=
            '<div class="cust-dropdown-items"><a href="#" id="' +
            nplate +
            '" class="number-plate-links">' +
            nplate +
            " " +
            full_name +
            "</a></div>";
        
      }
      // now you do things with `dropdown_content`
    });
}
```

Comment: `get_full_name_by_nplate(vehicle_data,nplate).then((full_name) =>` this would become simply `full_name = get_full_name_by_nplate(vehicle_data,nplate);` correct?

Comment: I mean, there is no promise in the `get_full_name_by_nplate(vehicle_data,nplate)` function now as you have written it. Or is there? Do I still need to await for a promise there?

Comment: `nplate_list` takes the correct value at `nplate_list = user_data["number_plates"];` but then in `for (nplate of nplate_list) {` it is undefined.

Comment: Oh sorry, yes, I forgot to take the.promise away

Comment: Did you possibly to forget the declaration on the first line of the loadUserData function? I don't see any reason how it could become undefined before the program enters the last callback.

Comment: I did not forget. I got the code working but i had to pass nplate_list as a parameter from one .then to the other... so there is still one nesting.. not ideal but at least it works now. I will post the code i have at the moment so that you can see.