# Return value from Firestore instead of console.logging it. - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore

I've looked at the firestore doc. on how to retrieve data and it works fine. But I am not able to store the value in a variable. I've taken a look  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59537257/how-to-return-value-from-firestore-database) How to return value from firestore database? but the answer end result is still a `console.log(result);`.

```
function returnUserData(userId){
  let docRef = db.collection("users").doc(userId)
  return docRef.get().then((doc) => {
    if (doc.exists) {
        doc.data()
        return doc.data();
    } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
  }).catch((error) => {
      console.log("Error getting document:", error);
  });
}
returnUserData(localStorage.getItem("currentUserId")).then(result => {
  console.log(result);
})
```

How would I be able to return an actual value of `returnUserData`?

Comment: The value is already stored in a variable. You have named it `result`

Comment: If I try using `console.log(result)` somewhere else I get result is not defined.

Comment: `result` is only within scope of your `.then()` callback function. What is it you want to do with the result? Where do you want to use it?

Comment: I'm trying to run the returnUserData, store it in a variable and use this in a useState.

Answer (score 2):

In a typical React app where you want to set a state value from the result, you would make async calls like this within a `useEffect` hook and set the state value after it resolves

```js
const [doc, setDoc] = useState()

useEffect(() => {
  returnUserData(localStorage.getItem("currentUserId")).then(result => {
    setDoc(result)
  })
}, [])
```

Comment: HA! This works fine. I never though about using a useEffect(), thak you so much! I will accept when cooldown finishes

Comment: The `useEffect` with an empty array of dependencies only runs once when your component mounts. See https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects